# Orthogonal vectors generation with constraints

Tags: geometry

I need to generate a set of orthogonal vectors. The catch is that they are constrained:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^N \mu_i = 0$,

for every $\vec{\mu}$ and

$\mu_i \in \{-1, 1\}$.

For a space of $N$ dimension $50\%$ of elements are $1$ and the other $50\%$ are $-1$.

In my application I use only 2 and it's fairly easy to generate them using brute force. The think is, there appears to be a limitation. Bellow a certain $N$, the percentage constraint is violated to achieve orthogonal vectors, if I keep the percentage constraint then the sum constraint is violated.
Can anyone help me develop e mathematical formulation of my orthogonal vector with constraints?

Comment: How are the $\mu$s related to the vectors?

Comment: So for example, in $2D$ $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ are the sort of thing you want? Or does $(1,1)$ not work because its components sum to $2$ and not $0$?  In which case how can you do it for $2D$?

Comment: In $3D$ I don't think it is possible; I think it can only be done with even $N$.  Otherwise any dot product will not be $0$; you can't add an odd number of $1$'s and $-1$'s to get $0$.

Comment: actually I think the dimension must be a multiple of 4, to satisfy the sum constraint, choose half of the coordinates to be negative. A second vector satisfying the sum constraint and orthogonal to the first must have half of the negative co-ordinates the same as the first and half of them different.

Comment: @Aruralreader: \vec{\mu} are the vectors and \mu_i are the components

Comment: @RobertTheTutor: That is exactly it! There are some dimensions, like 2D that the dot product between 2 vectors can be zero but the sum will not be. Even dimensions are also a restriction, as you said. I think my question is, is there a way, mathematically, to show which dimensions are possible and what is the lower dimension?

Comment: @WW1: I'll try that